# Query build with multiple join parameters on laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

This is the sql query:

```
select tags.desc as areas,
    COUNT(planificacion_info.id_area) as cantidad_intervenciones,
    SUM(CASE WHEN planificacion_info.tipo_geometria = 'Polygon' and 
        planificacion_info.estado = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as poligonos, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN planificacion_info.tipo_geometria = 'LineString' and 
        planificacion_info.estado = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as lineas, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN planificacion_info.tipo_geometria = 'Point' and planificacion_info.estado = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as puntos,
    min(planificacion_info.created_at::time) as hora from "tags" 
left join 
    "planificacion_info" on "planificacion_info"."id_area" = "tags"."id_tag"   and 
        "tags"."estado" = true and 
        "planificacion_info"."estado" = true and planificacion_info.created_at::Date = ('2018-03-09')
where 
    tags.grupo = 'area'
group by "tags"."desc"
```

I need to parse it to Query Build, I have it but it does not work properly:

```
$areas = \DB::table('tags')
        ->leftJoin('planificacion_info', function($query) use($fecha){
            $query->on('planificacion_info.id_area', '=', 'tags.id_tag')
            ->where('tags.grupo','=','area')
            ->where('tags.estado','=','true')
            ->where('planificacion_info.estado','=','true')
            ->where(DB::raw('planificacion_info.created_at::Date'), '=', $fecha);
        })
        ->selectRaw("tags.desc as areas, COUNT(planificacion_info.id_area) as cantidad_intervenciones, SUM(CASE WHEN planificacion_info.tipo_geometria = 'Polygon' and planificacion_info.estado = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as poligonos,
        SUM(CASE WHEN planificacion_info.tipo_geometria = 'LineString' and planificacion_info.estado = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as lineas,
        SUM(CASE WHEN planificacion_info.tipo_geometria = 'Point' and planificacion_info.estado = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as puntos,
        min(planificacion_info.created_at::time) as hora")
->groupBy('tags.desc');
```

I see the problem in the join sentence.
This not work correctly.
Thanks.

This is the result:

```
[ { "areas":"Ambiente y Espacio P\u00fablico",
    "cantidad_intervenciones":"0",
    "poligonos":"0",
    "lineas":"0",
    "puntos":"0",
    "hora":null
  },
  { "areas":"Arbolado",
    "cantidad_intervenciones":"0",
    "poligonos":"0",
    "lineas":"0",
    "puntos":"0",
    "hora":null
   }, ...
```

I think that this line is not working:

```
->where('tags.grupo','=','area')
```

Comment: Define "not work correctly".  Error messages?  Then show us the error messages.  Unexpected results?  Then show us the input, the results and the results you expected.

Comment: I'm receiving data, but not total of tags.desc, only those that have a total data.

Comment: `Unexpected results? Then show us the input, the results and the results you expected.`  Perhaps reading this may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your original query the `where()` constraint is outside the `leftJoin()`:

```php
$areas = \DB::table('tags')
    ->leftJoin('planificacion_info', function($query) use($fecha) {
        ...
    })
    ->where('tags.grupo','=','area')
    ->selectRaw(...)
    ->groupBy('tags.desc');
```

Comment: all where() outside?

Comment: According to the original query only this one.